# Mixture of Multi-Level columns & Regular Columns

Tags: python, pandas

It is straightforward to create Pandas dataframes with Multi-level columns like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dat = np.random.randn(5, 4)
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Truck','Car'],
                                     ['Speed','Position']],
                                    names=['',''])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=header)
```

to get

[image]

However, I require a table such as the one below (addition of the Age column). Is this possible using Pandas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always need `MultiIndex`, there is possible use empty string for some level like:

```
df2[('', 'Age')] = np.random.randn(5)
print (df2)
      Truck                 Car                    
      Speed  Position     Speed  Position       Age
0  1.224236 -0.545658  0.906748 -0.982617 -0.654448
1 -0.633162  0.825520 -1.284497 -0.347309 -0.672104
2 -1.077761  0.972575  0.412191 -0.132086  0.870368
3 -0.673351  1.222222 -0.926413  1.424994  1.003245
4 -0.124790  0.705492  0.719548  0.141464 -0.366450

print (df2.columns)
MultiIndex([('Truck',    'Speed'),
            ('Truck', 'Position'),
            (  'Car',    'Speed'),
            (  'Car', 'Position'),
            (     '',      'Age')],
           )
```

If pass single column in last versions pandas convert second level to empty string:

```
df2['Age'] = np.random.randn(5)
print (df2)
      Truck                 Car                 Age
      Speed  Position     Speed  Position          
0  1.128052  0.792584 -1.750842 -0.808869 -1.330033
1 -1.412602 -0.803010  0.798280  1.755996  1.261033
2 -0.075504  0.420177  0.156556 -0.056861 -0.648126
3 -0.538234  0.901387  0.224944  1.277788  2.245300
4  0.629269  0.361891  3.638726 -1.201221 -1.012394

print (df2.columns)
MultiIndex([('Truck',    'Speed'),
            ('Truck', 'Position'),
            (  'Car',    'Speed'),
            (  'Car', 'Position'),
            (  'Age',         '')],
           )
```